# Passing arguments in R function

Tags: r, function, arguments, match

I am trying to writing a small function to match two groups. Within each pair, the two groups have the same values in `a` and `b` values and closest in `c`.

```
df <- structure(
  list(group = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
       a = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
       b = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
       c = c(0.13, 0.64, 0.34, 0.36, 0.3, 0.81, 0.83, 0.98, 0.13, 0.36, 0.51, 0.26, 0.64, 0.43)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

pairit <- function(data, case, id) {
   A = df[which(df$group == 1), ]
   B = df[which(df$group == 0), ]
   A$id = c(1:nrow(A))
   B$id = NA
   for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
      B$TMP <- (B$a == A$a[i] & B$b == A$b[i] & is.na(B$id))
      B$dif = abs(B$c - A$c[i])
      B <- B[order(-B$TMP, B$dif),]
     if (B$TMP[1]) B$id[1] = A$id[i]
   }
   B <- B[!names(B) %in% c("TMP", "dif")]
   new_df <- rbind(A, B)
   colnames(new_df)[colnames(new_df)=="id"] <- paste0(id)
   return(new_df)
}

# The following worked, but I directly entered augments into the function   

pairit(data = df, case="group == 1", id="pid")
```

It did not pass the arguments: `data = df` and `case = "group == 1"` to the function as I had directly entered those arguments into the function: `A = df[which(df$group == 1), ]` and `B = df[which(df$group == 0), ]`. I have tried to use something like `paste0(data, "$", case)` and `eval(paste0(data, "$", case))` to replace `df$group == 1`, but unsuccessful. Any suggestion and explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try `[[`, for example, `A <- data[ data[["group"]]== 1, ]` (the `which` is unnecessary here). The `"group"` could be a variable parsed from the function parameters.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, @mt1022. I will try it later.

Comment: @mt1022  Just let you know it works well. For more general use of the function,  I used `A = data[data[[paste0(case)]] == 1, ]` and  
  `B = data[data[[paste0(case)]] == 0, ]`.

Comment: It seems that `paste0` is also unnecessary, you can use `data[[case]]` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks.